# How do I export email account settings from Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there a way to actually export email account settings in Outlook 2010? By account settings I mean things like incoming and outgoing servers, account names, user names, passwords and connection settings like security and port setting.

I have like 16 email accounts and for this reason, I really have to say that I hate reinstalling Outlook! I don't even need to reinstall Outlook, but since Outlook is part of the Office 2010 suite and I need to reinstall it, it is inevitable. I know that this was not possible in previous versions, but I don't know about 2010. I only read about some registry hacks but I'm not sure it even works.

Comment: The Office 2013 uses a different path
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles

Comment: Okay @g.harika, I will be reinstalling Office 365 soon and I will check this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are familiar with the Registry Editor, navigate to and export;

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook`.

After you move your PST file over, import this registry entry to the new PC. It will have all of your account settings. You may have the enter the password for each of those 16 accounts.

Comment: So this will work even if I am not moving from one PC to another? I just need to reinstall Office, I am not migrating to a different computer. I will definitely try this, and I hope it works. If it fails I guess I will just have to add every single account manually again. I have all the settings noted down, it's just an inconvenience to have to add all that information manually. I'm OK with typing in the passwords again.

Comment: Yes. Just make sure you save the `.reg` file in a safe place so it doesn't get deleted when you uninstall Office. Then after the reinstall, run the reg file and it will restore the settings.

Comment: FYI, if you do this, the imported account takes over and obliterates any default Outlook/Exchange account that exists on the target computer.

Comment: My God - it's all binary blobs!  Why can't Microsoft give me a nice textual report of my email accounts/servers/network settings (even if passwords aren't included)?  I guess I'll have to schlep through the configuration dialog boxes and write all that stuff down.  Cripes.

Comment: With latest Outlook and Windows, this does not work for me. There is no such key. I did find profile information under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676`, but they are keys grouped with some other keys for things other than just my email accounts, and I am loathe to try to figure out Outlook's opaque storage scheme and risk corrupting Outlook's registry info adding new keys from my old computer. :(

Answer (score -1):

FILE > OPTIONS > ADVANCED >> in the EXPORT section CLICK the "Export" BUTTON

You may need to do this for each account

Comment: I attempted your solution and it does not achieve the desired result and it is not a complete set of instructions. There is no way to save the account information that sammyg is requesting using this. In the future please write complete instructions in your answer and address the items that the question requires. Thank you for trying to be helpful!